# Derivative of absolute value using epsilon delta

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, absolute-value, epsilon-delta

I want to show that
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}=\frac{x}{|x|},$$
for $x\ne 0$.

Take $x\ne 0$ and let $\epsilon>0$. Then
$$\left|\frac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}-\frac{x}{|x|}\right|\leq\frac{|x+h||x|+|x|^{2}+|x||h|}{|x||h|}=\frac{|x+h|}{|h|}+\frac{|x|}{|h|}+1$$

How can I choose $\delta>0$ such that $|h|<\delta$ implies
$$\frac{|x+h|}{|h|}+\frac{|x|}{|h|}+1<\epsilon?$$

Any hints?

Comment: Perhaps realise that it is not differentiable at zero, but other than that point notice it is simply $x$ or $-x$, with easy derivative

Comment: @FShrike Quite right. But since I am trying to get better at epsilon delta proofs, I would like to prove it in the above manner.

Comment: Hint: discuss two cases of $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Comment: Notice that if you multiply numerator and denominator by $|x+h|+|x|$ then $\dfrac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}$ reduces to $\dfrac{2x+h}{|x+h|+|x|}$ Since it is apparent from this form that the limit as $h\to0$ is $\dfrac{x}{|x|}$ that would be a better place to start looking for $\delta$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is that since $x\neq 0$ and $h\ll |x|$

you can select $\delta=\frac 12|x|$ so that $|h|<\delta\implies x+h$ and $x$ have the same sign

(*Rem: $\frac x2<x+h<\frac{3x}2$ if $x>0$ and $\frac {3x}2<x+h<\frac{x}2$ if $x<0$*)

This means there exists $\sigma=\pm 1$ such that $|x|=\sigma x$ and $|x+h|=\sigma(x+h)$.

The expression becomes $$\dfrac{|x+h|-|x|}{h}=\dfrac{\sigma(x+h)-\sigma x}{h}=\dfrac{\sigma h}h=\sigma\to \sigma=\dfrac{|x|}{x}=\dfrac x{|x|}$$

You don't even need an epsilon, the expression is constant as soon as $h$ gets sufficiently small (in fact we can even refine to $|h|<|x|$ instead of $\frac 12|x|$).

See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x0b076shwg